# Kotlin Unit Test variable declaration lateinit vs lazy vs nullable vs non-nullable

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

We are converting most of our unit tests from Java to Kotlin. What's the best way to declare a variable in our unit tests (across but not all some might still have use cases to use lateinit, lazy, nullable etc...) and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe lateinit, lazy, nullable and non-nullable are good features in Kotlin also in the unit test.

you might know that 
lateinit is working only with var `lateinit var`, this gives the following features:

1. you can initialize `lateinit var` from any part of the project, so
   this gives you the ability to initialize the variable maybe within
   your test case
2. `lateinit var` doesn't work with non-nullable values, so you can assign a null value to lateinit variable and check its nullability as a test case.
3. in `lateinit var` you can change the value frequently, and since you are changing values, it increases your test cases, hence your coverage.

while in lazy, it works only with val, `val ins by lazy{}`

- This is a good practice when you have a singleton (object class) and your test cases are dependant on this instance, so you create it once `by lazy`

I do recommend reading [this article](https://phauer.com/2018/best-practices-unit-testing-kotlin/) about best practice in kotlin.

I hope this was good.

Comment: The article was really good, read some practices that I could apply. I am using @Mock annotation, PowerMock btw.

Comment: `lazy` can be nullable?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the use:

**Safe calls(?.):**
This helps to avoid the NullPointerException. It calls method/property with the help of an object if that object is not null, else returns null (Not NPE). This is simply a null check.

**The !! Operator:**
This is used to explicitly assert that property is not null. But if it is null then it throws NullPointerException

**Lateinit:**
Using lateinit, the initial value does not need to be assigned. We can initialize it later. We don't need to initialize anything until we need it.

This is just a short explanation for more details I found below blogs useful, please check:
https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/safe-calls-vs-null-checks-in-kotlin-f7c56623ab30
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit/